# Creating high quality video/audio pi stream

Tags: pi-3, audio, streaming-video, streaming, raspivid

I have a question regarding creating a video/audio high quality stream using a raspberry pi. I'm getting married in 3 weeks, and my father who has lost the majority of his vision in one eye just had the retina in his other detach. Because of this, he won't be able to come (he can't fly, has to be facedown for a few weeks, etc). I already made a photobooth using a raspberry pi, but in order that he can see/more importantly hear the wedding, I was going to use the same one to set up a live stream with the Rpi Samsung camera and a high quality usb microphone. Because our wedding is outside (but close enough to a router), I was also going to attach a battery pack to it. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to create a live stream that incorporates both the camera and a usb microphone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love the pi or I wouldn't be here, but I'm going to make a friendly suggestion:  You probably have a lot to deal with in the next 3 weeks and obviously this is an important goal.  Is it possible with a pi?  Sure.  But it could also be sketchy, difficult, and unpredictable.  You do not want to discover something you didn't think about or know could happen because it fails to deliver on the big day.  So you might want to consider buying something dedicated to this purpose.  Is it going to cost more than a pi and camera? Probably...

Comment: ...Is it going to be as useful for other general purpose things?  Probably not.  But if you pay for something designed explicitly for idiot-proof A/V streaming then you will be saving yourself a gamble and time.  Also, you'll need to stream this through a server, and some such products include that, possibly via subscription.  One possibility to consider along these lines would be **smart phone app**.  Either way remember you'll likely want on site wifi with high available bandwidth.  And don't allow your guests access or they'll choke you out inadvertantly.

Comment: I would very much belt-and-braces this. Get a good buddy with reasonable Google-fu to make the attempt on the Pi setup - it's not too difficult, and it's pretty solidly documented, although it can become time consuming to iron out the niggles. I would also acquire (beg/borrow/steal) a decent smartphone with a nice camera, and Skype the whole thing at extravagant personal expense in terms of bandwidth costs. The peace of mind is worth the irritation, and you'll have some nice extra video afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same rPi? It depends on what you're using to capture the images for your photo booth. If I were in your shoes, I think I would consider using motioneyeos, found here: https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki

I would consider just buying another pi zero if needed, as it is an entire OS for the rPi, but would give you what you're after. The real question is, will your venue allow you access to the router so you can set up port forwarding? I sure hope so. Best of luck.

Comment: I would also say I agree with goldilocks on this one. Let someone else do it, with a reliable pre-built solution. I have an android app that turns my phone into an ip camera. When in doubt, KISS.